# Database auto backup with current data and time

Tags: mysql

I am trying to take auto backup of `Mysql` database from batch file with current date and time, but it take backup with 0 Kb.

```
echo on

set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%%DATE:~6,4%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%

CD "C:\Program Files\MySql\MySql Server 5.7\bin"

mysqldump -hlocalhost -uusername -ppassword databasename > D:\%TIMESTAMP%.sql
```

Above code generate sql file on location with current date and time, but with 0 kb 
means blank database.

Comment: i don't beöieve that your code has anything to do with vb net

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me just using your own directory.

https://github.com/improy/MySQL-DataBase-backup-using-windows-bat-file/blob/master/MySqlBackup.bat